# Serial comunication problem Arduino - Python

Tags: python, arduino

I'm fairly new to coding and I need to get a project done for a class in which the teacher barely explains what he's doing. I need my PC (through Python) to send and receive data from my Arduino board. So far, I seem to be receiving something, but I need float values to make a couple plots and I'm completely lost. Any help would be appreciated :(

Python:

```
#Librerias
import serial
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Comunicación Serial
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3',9600,timeout = 2);
time.sleep = 1;
t = 0; #Noisy Signal
d_señal = []; #For plots
d_filtro = [];
while (t <= 1):
    señal = np.sin(2*np.pi*5*t) + 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*50*t);
    t=t+0.3;
    d_señal.append(str(señal)); #**

for i in d_señal:
    arduino.write(i.encode('utf-8')); 
    salida = arduino.readline().decode('utf-8'); 
    d_filtro.append(salida);
print(d_filtro);
arduino.close();
```

Arduino:

```
String IncomingByte; //Serial Data
float x[] = {0,0,0};  
float y[] = {0,0,0};
float valor = 0.0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    IncomingByte = Serial.read();
    valor = IncomingByte.toFloat();
    x[0] = valor;
    y[0] = 1.91122623*y[1] + -0.91500257*y[2] + 0.00094408*x[0] + 0.00188817*x[1] + 0.00094408*x[2];
    delay(10); //10ms
    
    for(int i = 1; i >= 0; i--){
      x[i+1] = x[i]; 
      y[i+1] = y[i];
    }
    
    Serial.print(y[0]); 
  }
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
['', '0.050.230.571.071.722.513.414.415.516.707.969.2910.6712.1013.5515.0316.5318.0919.7421.4023.02', '24.6226.1727.6729.1430.5932.0133.3934.7436.0537.3338.5639.7440.8741.9442.9643.9244.8345.6846.5247.3948.2349.01', '49.7350.3850.9851.5352.0552.5452.9953.4253.8254.2054.5454.8455.1155.3455.5555.7155.8555.9556.0756.2656.4456.59']
```

Thank you to anyone who reads this.
​

Comment: You are using `.readline()` to receive data from the Arduino, but you're never actually sending a newline from the Arduino - so all of your data is being concatenated together, until the `.readline()` finally times out.

Comment: Where can I add the newline if I'm working with data from a list?

Comment: You just need to use `.println()` instead of `.print()` on the Arduino side.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I just need to figure out what to do from there, you're a saviour.